# How to set route path correctly in Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

http://xxxx/api/garmin/data throws the following error

> No type was found that matches the controller named 'garmin'.

Below is the code in `Global.asax`

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ControllerAndAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
     );

     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new QueryStringMapping("type", "json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));
     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new QueryStringMapping("type", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
}
```

Controller Code

```
public class GraminController : ApiController
{
    // GET
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("data")]
    public string GetGarminData()
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

The above code worked on the development server, but throws the below error

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request
>   URI 'http://xxxx/api/garmin/data'.  No type
>   was found that matches the controller named
>   'garmin'.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the error?

Comment: Yes, in Fiddler mentioned 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' 
I am trying to make a simple GET request work, but that also fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller name `Gramin` but you are trying to access it using `garmin`. Map you route this way

```
public class GraminController : ApiController
{
    // GET
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/garmin/data")]
    public string GetGarminData()
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

or if you want to use your way then make the call

http://xxxx/api/gramin/data

Comment: Thank you Mostafiz ..... I somehow missed that. Such a silly error. It's working now. Cause of simple spelling error, spent hrs trying to troubleshoot. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask a question ... in the above code [Route ...] I am not able to define a [Route] attritube. Is there a namespace I need to import ?

Comment: `System.Web.Http` namespace, or directly `System.Web.Http.Route()`

Comment: Thanks Mostafiz, for some reason can't seem to import System.Web.Http.Route and the only import namespace I get is System.Web.Http.Routing.